# Android studio attempts to build for all ABIs, while I defined only one. Suggestions?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, abi

Here is my problem. I am working on an already quite large Android application, and am adding a native library.

I would like to build only for armeabi-v7a while I am testing, for various reasons. My test phone has this abi, and I have issues building some third party libraries with some ABIs at the moment.

Now, I already googled / SEed for how to filter ABIs.

I have added in my app build.gradle the following :

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include  'armeabi-v7a'
    }
}
defaultConfig {
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }

}
```

To be safe, I duplicated this config in my modules build.gradle.

However, running a build results in CMake errors, saying it cannot find some tools for ABIs mips and x86_64.  (I actually don't have them)

It would really help if someone could suggest why gradle would ignore the abi configuration entries, and how I could solve this.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. Could you provide a complete minimal example? Also, have you tried adding `ndk { abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a' }` inside your `defaultConfig`?

Comment: Thanks. I have tried adding ndk{...} without any success. Ok I will make a minimal example.

Comment: splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include  'armeabi-v7a'
    }
} may not be needed.

Comment: if you just want to enforce one ABI, the `abiFilters` line is enough. Be aware that this only applies to your current module.

Comment: I surprisingly cannot reproduce my issue in a minimal example. Is it possible that another project property not defined in a build.gradle be significant ?

Comment: Does your real project and the minimal example project use the same gradle version and Android gradle plugin version?

Comment: Yes, both are running with gradle 4.1 and gradle plugin 2.3.3

Comment: Is your defaultConfig within the android block of your gradle file?